# I need help to build a method that returns an array

Tags: java, arrays, methods

So, i'm a beginner in Java, and my teacher wants me to build a method that returns an Array of two elements.
This is what i've made

```
public int[] getXY() {
    int[] a = new int[2];
    a[0]=getX();
    a[1]=getY();
    return a;
}
```

getX and getY returns this.x and this.y respectively.
So obviously this method returns the reference to the array, not the elements of the array itself, which is what i want to do, but i've no ideas.
He made it clear that the method has to return an Array of two elements, so that's why i didn't make it with String.
Any suggestions?

Comment: If you are an beginner, and your prof asked you that, maybe it's a good idea you try to solve this problem yourself. I'm sure your prof will be glad to help you if you have difficulties. Stackoverflow is not the right place for you to ask this kind of question.

Comment: @JOSE do you want to return something like a Tuple?

Comment: What's wrong with this method? It returns an array with two elements.

Comment: @Nicolas i ended up talking to him and he told me that this is what he wanted. I was supposed to later use this method inside a print, so that's why i thought it was wrong, bc in the outputs i was clearly getting the reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have got is the correct solution. In Java, you cannot get the "array itself." All you can have is a reference to the array.

This sounds like a simple miscommunication. Since you can only have a reference to an array (or to any object in general) - never the array itself, people sometimes use loose language and say *"this method returns an array"* when they mean *"this method returns a reference to an array"*.